# Deploying to rinkeby doesn't work

Tags: web3js, rpc

It seems I have a bit of trouble deploying a contract to testnet through infura

this is my code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');

var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/ETw0GZkwyCWpiOLpvHAw'));

var account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('5e8bdde40096190506b3182c29aaf068ef5ff3b0dc989ee7e0874ca6873b9fe5');

var _randomSeed = 12; var myContractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract([...]);

myContractInstance.deploy({
     data: '0x...',
     arguments:[_randomSeed]  }).send({
    from: account.address//,
    // gas: 1500000,
    // gasPrice: '30000000000000' 
}, function(error, transactionHash){ console.log(error, transactionHash); })
        .on('error', function(error){ console.log(error); })
        .on('transactionHash', function(transactionHash){ console.log(transactionHash); })
        .on('receipt', function(receipt){
            console.log(receipt.contractAddress) // contains the new contract address
        })
        .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){ console.log(confirmationNumber, receipt); })
        .then(function(newContractInstance){
            console.log(newContractInstance.options.address) // instance with the new contract address
        });
```

I am able to get the balance of an address so it connects to the node but I get this error when I do .send() after .deploy()

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-core-helpers\src\errors.js:42:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-providers-http\src\index.js:60:32)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-providers-http\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-providers-http\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-providers-http\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:509:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-providers-http\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:469:24)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9) undefined
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-core-helpers\src\errors.js:42:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-providers-http\src\index.js:60:32)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-providers-http\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-providers-http\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-providers-http\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:509:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-providers-http\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:469:24)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
    at Object.InvalidResponse (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-core-helpers\src\errors.js:42:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-providers-http\src\index.js:60:32)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-providers-http\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:64:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-providers-http\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:354:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-providers-http\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:509:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (E:\workspace\Ethereum\DeployContract\node_modules\web3\packages\web3-providers-http\node_modules\xhr2\lib\xhr2.js:469:24)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Do you have any idea why this happens or how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

try adding your account to the in-memory wallet using your private key or the  account object you get from `privateKeyToAccount()`:

```
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(privateKey || account)

console.log(web3.eth.accounts.wallet.length) //=> 1
```

[See the Web3 1.0 docs for more info](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-add)

Answer (score 0):

Deploying via Infura can be very tedious at time.

Since you are trying to deploy on Rinkeby, should be easier with a local node at your end. Both Geth and Parity are quick to sync over Rinkeby (use fast option on Geth and warp option on Parity).